# How do I find explicit formula and show that the sequence tends to converge to $(0,0)$?

Tags: linear-algebra

In $\mathbb{R}^2$, the sequence $(x_n,y_n)$, $n\in \mathbb{N}_0$ is recursively defined:
$\begin{pmatrix}x_{n+1}\\ y_{n+1}\end{pmatrix}=\left (\begin{matrix}0 & 1\\ 1/4 &0 \end{matrix} \right )\begin{pmatrix}x_n\\ y_n\end{pmatrix}$
So for $(x_0,y_0)=(4,0)$. I have found some follow members: $(x_1,y_1)=(0,1),(x_2,y_2)=(1,0),(x_3,y_3)=(0,1/4),(x_4,y_4)=(1/0)$
But still I don’t know how to find explicit formula and show convergency to (0,0).

Comment: What is $(x_4,y_4)$ again?

Answer (score 2):

Find eigenvalues of the recursion matrix:

$$|xI-A|=\begin{vmatrix}x&-1\\-\frac14&x\end{vmatrix}=x^2-\frac14=0\iff x=\pm\frac12$$

Now eigenvectors:

$$\lambda=-\frac12\;:\;\;-\frac12x-y=0\implies x=-2y\implies\;\text{for example}\;\;\binom{\;2}{-1}$$

$$\lambda=\frac12\;:\;\;\frac12x-y=0\implies x=2y\implies\;\text{for example}\;\;\binom{2}{1}$$

Form the conjugation marix:

$$P=\begin{pmatrix}2&2\\\!-1&1\end{pmatrix}\implies P^{-1}=\frac14\begin{pmatrix}1&\!-2\\1&2\end{pmatrix}\implies$$

$$P^{-1}AP= \begin{pmatrix}-\frac12&0\\0&\frac12\end{pmatrix}\implies A^n=P\begin{pmatrix}\frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{2^n}&0\\0&\frac1{2^n}\end{pmatrix}P^{-1}=\frac14\begin{pmatrix}\frac{(-1)^{n-1}+1}{2^{n-1}}&\frac{(-1)^{n-1}+1}{2^{n-2}}\\\frac{(-1)^{n-1}+1}{2^n}&\frac{(-1)^{n-1}+1}{2^{n-1}}\end{pmatrix}$$

so

$$\binom{x_{n+1}}{y_{n+1}}=A^n\binom{x_0}{y_0}=\frac14\begin{pmatrix}\frac{(-1)^{n-1}+1}{2^{n-1}}&\frac{(-1)^{n-1}+1}{2^{n-2}}\\\frac{(-1)^{n-1}+1}{2^n}&\frac{(-1)^{n-1}+1}{2^{n-1}}\end{pmatrix}\binom40=\binom{\frac{(-1)^{n-1}+1}{2^{n-1}}}{\frac{(-1)^{n-1}+1}{2^n}}\xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{}\binom00$$

Answer (score 2):

Let $T$ be the map $T(x,y) = (y,x/4).$ Our sequence has the form $T^n(x,y), n = 0, 1, \dots$ Note that $T^2(x,y) = (1/4)(x,y).$ Thus $T^{2n}(x,y) = (1/4^n)(x,y) \to (0,0).$ This implies $T^{2n+1}(x,y) = T(T^{2n}(x,y)) \to (0,0)$ by the continuity of $T.$ Thus $T^n(x,y) \to (0,0)$ for any $(x,y).$

Answer (score 1):

Using recursion, you can show that $\begin{pmatrix}x_{n}\\ y_{n}\end{pmatrix}=\left (\begin{matrix}0 & 1\\ 1/4 &0 \end{matrix} \right )^n\begin{pmatrix}x_0\\ y_0\end{pmatrix}$

But $A=\left (\begin{matrix}0 & 1\\ 1/4 &0 \end{matrix} \right )^n\to 0$ as $n\to \infty$ and the result follows.

To show this, it is enough to observe that $\det A=\left ( \frac{-1}{4} \right )^{n}, $ because the offdiagonal elements of the original matrix are zero.

Comment: Showing the determinants $\to 0$ does not imply the sequence of matrices $\to$ the zero matrix.

Comment: But in this case it does, because $A$ has zeros on the off diagonal. Powers of $A$ produce matrices that have either zeros on the off-diagonal or zeros on the diagonal.  If there are non-zero elements on the diagonal of the limit matrix, a standard argument using norms will show that there must be an $N\in \mathbb N$ s.t $A^n$ has nonzero diagonal elements if $n>N$. Similarly for the offdiagonals. So the limit matrix is $0$

Comment: But why even bring determinants into this?

Comment: The fact that the determinant goes to zero means that the limit matrix has lin dependent rows, which because of the form of $A^n$ implies all entries are zero. Your use of the continuity of the corresponding lin transformation seems to be equivalent to my appeal to the standard "norm argument".